# find_package(Boost REQUIRED) , cmakelist can found boost , can not found the boost components graph

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mingw

In windows11.
I have compiled the boost with mingw64.
`found_package(Boost REQUIRED)` is correct.
However,

`find_package(Boost 1.69.0 COMPONENTS graph REQUIRED)` 
got error, like this [image]

Comment: The good news is: Boost Graph is _largely_ header-only. If you require one of the features that isn't (`read_graphviz` e.g.), then you can check whether the installed boost library includes the DLL for it. If not, that's the problem.

Comment: You can work around it pretty easily by just adding `libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp` to your project directly.

Comment: Here's on old live example where I did just that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e96613787bbd58

Comment: I have a try, but it still has the same error in my cmakelist.